# How to configure security access in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm learning Spring and now trying to configure security. I need to create secured endpoints and one not secured for registration.
But when I'm trying to access http://localhost:8080/register I'm getting error "An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext" and "AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException".
I have repeated example in docs but still get this error.

**WebSecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/register").permitAll();
  }

  @Bean
  @Override
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
  }

}
```

**OAuth2Config.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
  private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

  @Autowired
  private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

  @Value("3600")
  private int expiration;

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {
    configurer.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    configurer.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.inMemory().withClient("app").secret("secret").accessTokenValiditySeconds(expiration)
        .scopes("read", "write").authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token").resourceIds("resource");
  }

}
```

**RegisterController.java**

```
@RestController
public class RegisterController {
  @Autowired
  UserDao userDao;

  @Autowired
  CityDao cityDao;


  @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ResponseEntity<?> addUser(@RequestParam(value = "email") String email, @RequestParam(value = "firstName") String firstName,
      @RequestParam(value = "lastName") String lastName, @RequestParam(value = "city") Long cityId,
      @RequestParam(value = "password") String password){
    User userToFind = userDao.findByEmail(email);
    City city = cityDao.findById(cityId).get();

    if (userToFind != null) {
      PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
      User user = new User(firstName, lastName, email, city, passwordEncoder.encode(password));
      return new ResponseEntity<>(userDao.save(user), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
    else{
      return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if it doesnt Require security why dont you simply remove it from your restrictive list.

Comment: @georgesvan I need to disable security on /register point and enable on others. I have tried few variants but it won't work.

Comment: Is this a spring-boot application ?

Comment: @Bala Yes, it is.